# How to make the value of number2 equal to number only once

Tags: java

I am trying to make the value of number2 the value of number for only the first iteration of the loop. The only ways I have been able to figure out is how to make the value of number2 to number for the whole equation. ex: if I put 3 + 3 + 3 = the equation comes out to be 6 since number2 is set to number for the whole time, and number is set to 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      // Identifiers  
      int i = 1; // This int is what makes a ">" be printed on every new line.
      final String end = "=";      
      double number;
      String input;
      String input2;
      int yes;
      int index;
      int length;
      double math = 0;
      double number2;
      
      
      // Prompt for the user on how to input the numeric expression.      
      System.out.println("Enter your numeric expression in the following form:");
      System.out.println("number operator number operator number =");
      System.out.println("Leave a blank space after each number or operator.");
      System.out.println("Example: 3.5 * 3 - 5 / 2.5 =" + '\n');
      input = "0";
      
      
      
      
      
      while (!input.equals(end)) {        
                
       input = scnr.next();
       number = Double.parseDouble(input);
       number2 = number;       
      // System.out.println("num2 is: " + number2);
       System.out.println("input is: " + input);
       System.out.println("number is: " + number);
       input = scnr.next();
       switch(input) {  
          
            case "+":
               math = number2 + number; System.out.println("add" + math);
               break;
            case "-":
               math = number2 - number;  System.out.println("sub" + math);             
               break;
            case "*":
               math = number2 * number; System.out.println("mult" + math);
               break;
               case "/":
               math = number2 / number; System.out.println("div" + math); 
              
            
         }
         
         number2 = math;
        // System.out.println("num2 is: " + number2);
         
         
      }
      
      
     System.out.println("Answer: " + math);
      
    /*  double hiu = 3 / 2 * 3 - 2  + 1 ;
      System.out.println("yes " + hiu); */
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a boolean value outside of the loop `Boolean isFirstLoop = true;` then have an `if` statement inside that loop that does the special behaviour for the first loop, and sets the value false `isFirstLoop = true;`

Comment: I sort of see what you mean, but what would this look like in my code?

Comment: Something like: `Boolean isFirstLoop = true; while (!input.equals(end)) { if(isFirstLoop){/*Do special behaviour*/ isFirstLoop = false;} else {/*Do normal behaviour*/}}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to just move the code parsing the very first number out of the loop. You want it to happen once, not loop over it. Something like

```
String input = scanner.next();
double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
double number2;

while(!input.equals(end)) {
    input = scanner.next();

    switch(input) {
        case "+":
            input = scanner.next();
            number2 = Double.parseDouble(input);
            number = number + number2;
            break;
        case "-":
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as always, it was a simple fix that I was trying to make much harder than it actually is. Nonetheless, I greatly appreciate your assistance with my issue!

Answer (score 0):

These are both solutions. You can also use a do-while loop, applying the logic of Sorifiend's answer. The deciding factors are going to be the trade-offs between computational complexity vs. code readability vs. modularity.

computational complexity:
if you are doing very many computations, and have no actual need to evaluate that the condition is met before setting the variable, then get that out of your loop.

code readability:
use a comment to establish the logic of pulling that process out of the loop. You need a variable declared outside of the loop to update/store your answer as the string is parsed. You may define this variable as 0.0 before parsing anything since this is a neutral value that will have no impact on the calculation.

modularity:
you do not want the external variable getting accidentally orphaned. This isn't particularly applicable to your use case. Just a concept to keep in mind as you progress through your journey.